# How to toggle my Ambient light in the scene on and off

Tags: opengl

In my scene, I have ambient light with values:

```
GLfloat global_ambient[] = {0.4, 0.4, 0.4};
```

And in my initGL I am enableing it:

```
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);
```

I want when I press "s" key to toggle the light on and off. I know how to toggle the light, my question is is there a method such as glEnagle and glDisable for the ambient light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it myself. In my KeyResponder method when the user presses the 's' key this is what I am doing:

```
if (key == 's'){
    if (isAmbientOn){
        //if it is true turn the ambient off by setting the R,G,B values to 0
        global_ambient[0] = 0;
        global_ambient[1] = 0;
        global_ambient[2] = 0;
        isAmbientOn = false;
    }
    else{
        //if it is false tuen the ambient on by setting it to a value - 0.4
        global_ambient[0] = 0.4;
        global_ambient[1] = 0.4;
        global_ambient[2] = 0.4;
        isAmbientOn = true;
    }
}
```

And in my DrawScene method:

```
void CDrawModel::myDrawGLScene(GLvoid)      // Here's Where We Do All The Drawing{
//set up the ambient light in myDrawGLScene so we can switch it on and off on 's' key press...
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);

{
```